# Prove from rigorous definition that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n+{a_n}^2}{n-a_n}=1$ exists.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is my proof correct ?

Its given
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } a_n=1$
I have to prove from rigorous definition of limit that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n+{a_n}^2}{n-a_n}=1$ exists.

I will try to use the fact that for $n>>1$ or for sufficiently large n , $|a_n-1|<1$ , which implies $0<a_n<2$.

Now for estimating N ,
$|\frac{n+{a_n}^2}{n-a_n}-1|=|\frac{{a_n}^2+a_n}{n-a_n}|$

$|\frac{{a_n}^2+a_n}{n-a_n}|<|\frac{6}{n-2}|$

Let N $=2+\frac{6}{\varepsilon}$

For each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a natural number N such that for all $n>N$ , $|\frac{n+{a_n}^2}{n-a_n}-1|<{\varepsilon}$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks for feedback  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first choose $N_0$ such that $|a_n-1| <1$ for $n >N_0$. Then choose $N$ the way you have done and take the maximum of $N_0$ and $N$. Call this $M$. Then the desired inequality holds for $n >M$. (Also the last sentence is wrongly written).

Comment: so do l have to simply state for $n>N_0$ and then proceed as you told. Since it's a general sequence, we cannot describe $N_0$.

Comment: Yes, unless we know what exactly $(a_n)$ is we cannot find $N_0$ explicitly.  @AristotleStagiritis